# Using an Outside Channel Field in related_entries

Tags: expressionengine

Is it possible (or what is the best method) to use a channel field name that is coming from the outside of a related_entries tag? Like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="test"}
    {channel_field_name} <!-- Works here! -->
    {related_entries id="test2"}
        {channel_field_name} <!-- This won't work! -->
    {/related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Please consider reposting at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This was asked earlier today on the EE StackExchange site. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/496/is-it-possible-to-access-channel-variables-inside-of-a-reverse-related-entries-t#answer-512

Comment: Ah great, I wasn't able to post there awhile ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this topic covered it on the ExpressionEngine Stack Exchange earlier:

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/496/is-it-possible-to-access-channel-variables-inside-of-a-reverse-related-entries-t#answer-512